# How to fix a total to 2 decimal places html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, currency, decimal, cumulative-sum

I have the following javascript code to add checkboxes together when selected and produce a total. What do I need to add to the code to get the total to display 2 decimal places always.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTotal() {
document.listForm.total.value = '';
var sum = 68.50;
for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) { 
sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
}
}
document.listForm.total.value = sum;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call [`toFixed(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and pass the number of digits after the decimal point:

```
document.listForm.total.value = sum.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: do you have any idea why decimal numbers may not be adding together properly from that code?

Comment: @user2890036 Great, I forgot to tell you about `parseInt`. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toFixed()` method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function:

```
  function fixedPlace(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
  }
```

And call this function like:

```
var output = fixedPlace(3.1416);
```

It will return 3.14